# Watir-WebDriver: Find elements which class is not 'completed'

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I have a bunch of `li` elements. They are either with `uncompleted`, 'current' or `completed` class or without a class.

How do I find all `li` elements without `completed` class?

So far I am doing this by selecting necessary `li` objects from collection of `li` (through calling `#attribute_value('class')`, but maybe there is some elegant locating strategy in Watir-WebDriver?

**UPD:** As long as there is some misunderstanding of the question.

I want to know if there is locating strategy within Watir-WebDriver to find elements which class is not `completed`.

I know I can do this with Ruby and doing it like this:

```rb
browser.lis.select do |li|
  li.attribute_value('class') != 'completed'
end
```

But the question is if I can do this in one line by passing some argument to `#lis`

**UPD2:** Just realized that given class names narrows solutions. Updated question and sorry for that.

Comment: Your solution looks good enough to me.  I'm unaware of a way of doing this sort of thing directly through webdriver, but I'm no expert on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LI collection supports locators, which means you can do:

```
browser.lis(:class, 'uncompleted').each{ |x|
    puts x.text
}
```

**UPDATE**: For the case where there are multiple classes, you can modify the above to use a regex to check for not completed:

```
browser.lis(:class, /^(?!completed$)/).each{ |x| puts x.class_name }
```

This returns all `li` that have no class or are not exactly 'completed' (ex 'completed2').

Note: I think `.class_name` may have better support than `attribute_value('class')` (which I believe does not work in IE as it needs to be className).

Comment: This makes the assumption that the only li classes are 'completed' and 'uncompleted' (which may be accurate, but may not).

Comment: It looks like regexp is not correct `'completed' =~ /^(?!completed$)/ #=> nil`. However, I know see a way I can do this, thanks!

Comment: In this case `nil` is good, since it means it will not be included in the collection.

Answer (score 1):

In order to not assume that there are only two classes of arrays, you can do:

```
    all = browser.lis.collect { |li| li.class }
    completed = browser.lis(:class, 'completed').collect { |li| li.class }

    not_completed = (all - completed)
```

or even:

```
all = browser.lis.collect { |li| li.class }
not_completed = Array.new

all.each do |li|
    if li.class != "completed"
       not_completed << li
    end
end
```

Comment: I'm aware of such solution, but I've been looking for watir-webdriver built-in solution (if it exists). Updated the question.

Comment: I think these should actually be `li.class_name` instead of `li.class`. `li.class` will return Watir::LI rather than 'completed', 'uncompleted', etc.

Comment: I think all of the suggested solutions right now are more ruby based.  Are you just looking for a one-liner (emphasis on Webdriver native solution), or is there some other reason for a non-Ruby solution?

Comment: I wanted native solution and it looks like regexp helps there. Thanks for the answers however!