# Is it possible to web scrape a web-site if the style is set to style="display:none"

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, watir

This is what the CSS looks like

```
<ul class="offers general">

    <li class="offer ">

        <div id="offer-detail-384" class="hide" style="display:none">

            <div> Text I want to scrape is here </div>
```

I've successfully web scraped other web sites, but with this one it's giving me text back that I can't find anywhere on the page. It's a web site with a list of products and I'm getting back a list of products that I can't find anywhere on the site I'm scraping from. It's really odd...

The code is

```
@browser = Watir::Browser.new:phantomjs
@browser.goto "https://Groceries.com/offers"

@products = @browser.lis(class: "offer")

@products.each do |x|
    Groceries.create(title: x.divs[13].text, value: 
    x.divs[14].text)
end
```

So when I try to retrieve the data I'll get items like Nutrigrain bars, and what not but when I just look at the web site I'm scraping from there are no Nutrigrain bars to be found anywhere on the page.  I've double checked the link, I've web scraped other sites so I have a bit of an idea how to do it..

Comment: I'm not understanding your question. What do you mean by "it's giving me text back that I can't find on the page"? What do you want to retrieve, and what are you getting instead? Can you share your scraping code?

Comment: Added the code and description.  Thanks for taking the time to respond.

Comment: You may want to target the `div` elements and exclude any with a class of `hide`.

Comment: I tried targeting the div directly that contained the text data I wanted, but that didn't work either.  Gave me back products I couldn't find on the web page.

Comment: It could also possibly be changing the products up based on your cookies or location or whatnot. I've had to scrape sites before where I was getting vastly different results in my scraping than I was getting locally/seeing in my browser and it turned out to be because the server I was testing on was down in Georgia and I'm up here in Washington. I've also scraped sites where, when browser checking my results, I found different results in an incognito window/my scraper vs my normal window...Hard to say without actually knowing what site it is and such

Comment: I just had that thought..I just scraped the text of every div in the webpage and still can't find any products through it that are on the webpage that I look at.  Appreciate the help.  Is it possible the web site knows a bot is visiting the site and returning different data because of it?

Comment: Your last comment sounds like the opposite of your question. Are you getting results that aren't on the page, or are you not getting results that are on the page? They are different solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, try using a CSS selector to specifically exclude a class of `hide`:

```
@browser.div(css: ':not(.hide)')
```

I'm not sure how complete the CSS selector support is in webdriver. If this doesn't work, here's [a SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683853/watir-webdriver-find-elements-which-class-is-not-completed) which may have other ways to do the same thing.

**Edit**: here's another option which aims to select the `li` elements that don't contain hidden `div` elements:

```
@browser.element( :xpath, '//li[not(div/@class="hide")]' )
```

Comment: Watir is designed to not need to ever use XPath. There is a "visible" locator that matches what you have suggested: `@browser.div(visible: true)`, though I'm not sure that it will necessarily work for what is desired here.

Comment: Yeah, I know CSS and XPath better than I know the Watir API. `visible: true` seems the better way.

Answer (score 0):

`Element#text` should only return what is seen on the page, so you shouldn't be getting results that you can't actually see. It's hard to replicate when the code provided isn't real. Maybe you can try something like this:

```
@products = browser.div(id: /offer-detail-\d+/, visible: true).each do |x| 
    divs = x.divs      # only one wire call
    Groceries.create(title: divs[13].text, value: divs[14].text)
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding a class to the div could do the trick

HTML
`

```
    <li class="offer ">

        <div id="offer-detail-384" class="hide" style="display:none">

            <div class="scrape"> Text I want to scrape is here </div>`
```

CSS

`.scrape {display: block!important;}`